# How to open multiple instances of the same application from toolbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, productivity, toolbar

If I'm working on 2 instances of the same application (in this case, two instances of VSCode running), how do I make it so that if I click on the VSCode icon in the toolbar, both instances are open at the same time? I don't want to click on one and then the other every time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Shift + Right-click on the taskbar icon and select "Restore all windows".
You can also select "Show all windows side by side".

Note, there needs to be at least two windows of the same application already opened.

Comment: "Show all windows side by side" is the setting I want, but is there a way to make that the default action if I just click once on the icon?